# Idioms receiving by reference and private constructor are incompatible?

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference, factory, friend

I have `Some` class and `Factory` for this class.
`Factory` is friend to `Some`, and constructor of `Some` is private. I do it because I want that everyone can create new new instance of `Some` only via `Factory`.

Something like that:

```
class Some {
    friend class Factory;
    Some(..) {}
public:
    Some& operator=(const Some& s) {...}
};

class Factory {
public:
    Some makeSome(...) {
    ...
        return Some(...);
    };
};
```

Ok, this works. From another side I have some Queue wrapper (wrapped for synchronization reason). And it wrote in idiom "Every methods must return error code. Result passed only via argument references"

Something like:

```
template <class T>
class SyncQueue {
queue<t> m_q;
mutex m_m;
public:
....
    int Pop(T &t) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(m_m);
        if (m_q.empty())
           return 1;
        t = m_q.fromt();
        m_q.pop();
        return 0;
    }
};
```

As I understand I can't use this `SyncQueue` to pull `Some`, am I right?

Because code like this:

```
Some s;
if (queue(s)) {
   ...
}
```

Required Empty constructor for `Some`. And I have next options:

1. Make `public` empty constructor for `Some`
2. Make `private` empty constructor and add new `friend`s to `Some`
3. Using pointers

`Some` has some const members that must be initialize during construction (and only `Factory` knows this values). Also `Some` construction is heavy operation;

So all three options is bad:

1. Public constructor destroys idea about Factory.
2. A lot of friends not a good idea.
3. Pointers requirs to rewrite a lot of code. Also it is a big paine to use this.

Did i missed something, or there is no way to work it as I want?

Comment: You are right. I will edit post because of miss print

Comment: You will have to decide whether you want your class to be value-like (can be copied and put into collections by value), be resource-like (move-only, moved-from is some empty state) or have identity (cannot be copied or moved, should only be dealt with by pointer). Mixing these leads to the kind of mismatch issues that you're now experiencing.